# Adding basic marker to google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a marker to my customised google map API v3. The map is displaying fine but i can't seem to add a marker. This seems to be a basic thing to do, but i keep getting stuck. I've tried following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#AddingOverlays

However, my knowledge of javascript and API's in general is quite limited, so I feel must be missing something basic here. So basic that the Google instructions probably doesn't cover it. A missing colon, bracket. Maybe the variables are in the wrong sequence? Any input much appreciated! Here's the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.60505, -0.18989);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    //the code for the marker, as copy pasted from google
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });

    var styles = [
      {featureType: "landscape",
        stylers: [
          { color: "#378fb5" }
        ]
      },{
       ETC
       ETC
       ETC
        }
   ];

    map.setOptions({styles: styles});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to precise the map you want to use for the marker like this :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2):

You need to call

```
marker.setMap(map)
```

After you've created it, i.e

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.60505, -0.18989);

var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

//the code for the marker, as copy pasted from google
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});

// Add the marker to the map
marker.setMap(map);

var styles = [
  {featureType: "landscape",
    stylers: [
      { color: "#378fb5" }
    ]
  },{
   ETC
   ETC
   ETC
    }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag and drop the marker to your desired location, set draggable = true.

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable:true
        });